# Can someone help translate the calligraphy in this picture?

Tags: translation, calligraphy, poetry

This picture was a gift and is supposed to be a poem about the fjords in Hardanger, Norway. If someone could help translate the calligraphy, it would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Chinese Calligraphy]

Answer (score 2):

i would read it as:

我行哈ｘｘ高原 - 哈ｘｘ should be the transliteration of hardanger

上有白雪滿川垂

一車姍姍穿雪壁

ｘ望港口連雲天 - i suspected it’s “四”

唯見此處少花樹

敢ｘ瑞雪粧山川

挪威訪問西行道

冰下水流鳴潺潺

一九八一年六月 - june 1981

段雲 - the author name

the rhyming is, . . .

Comment: I would say it is 哈當利高原....上有白雪滿川巒..... 敢跨瑞雪粧山川

Comment: hmmm.... 段雲 sounds like 斷魂  in Cantonese

Answer (score 1):

水巷孑蠻 did most of the work already but didn't translate the text

Here it is

我行哈當利高原 - My trip to Hardanger Plateau

上有白雪滿川巒 - Above, there are rivers and mountains covered by white snow

一車姍姍穿雪壁 - A car slowly goes through walls of snow

四望港口連雲天 - Look around the cloud-cover sky above the harbor

唯見此處少花樹 - Just see this place has few plants

敢跨瑞雪粧山川 - Dare to walk across the snow-covered mountains

挪威訪問西行道 - The west route of visiting Norway

冰下水流鳴潺潺 - Flowing water's sound (can be heard) under the ice

一九八一年六月 - June 1981

段雲 - Duan Yun (the author's name)